# Handlebars - Best practice to handle UTM parameters

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, utm-tracking

The entire project is based on Handlebars (using HTML, css and JS).
I have a footer components that contains all the pages in my website (about, terms of service etc...).

When someone clicks on one of my campaigns (google ads for example), the URL to the homepage looks something like: `www.mysite.com?utm_source=Google&utm_term=...&...`

which indicates the source of the user.

On some pages, I have a form for leaving an email so I can contact the user in the future, this form is a specific component (contact.hbs).
When submitting an email, I append the UTM query parameters and handle them internally (sending myself internal emails, for example).

I want that every form will contain those UTM parameters that originated in the homepage.

### What is the best practice to handle those parameters?

I tried to save the in local storage and pass them with every link to a page containing a form that the user clicks, but it is not working using handlebars.

I was thinking that there must be a way to handle this internally, but I'm not sure exactly how.

Comment: I don't see this as a Handlebars question. How you decide to persist an identifier, like a UTM parameter, across a session is independent from your templating language. localStorage seems like a perfectly adequate solution to me, but you may have issues inserting the value into your templates if your templates are rendered server-side.

Comment: This was exactly my issue when I tried to inject the localStorage data.
I was wondering if there is a workaround. unfortunately, I can't avoid using handlebars in this project.

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with Handlebars. Your server will not be able to read data from your user's browser's localStorage regardless of what templating library, app framework and programming language you are using on your server. You would need to store these data in a way that is accessible by your server, like a cookie or server-side session.